College Drama Movie - identification
I watched this film about a decade ago and only remember a few details so I will be truly astounded if someone can identify this movie for me.  It takes place on a college campus. There is one scene where a guy eats mushrooms (psychedelic kind) and has sex with a girl who keeps morphing into an ex-girlfriend or something similar during his trip.
There is also an excellent montage where one character goes to Europe and it shows him partying hard, taking acid and going to clubs, and staying in very nice hotels because he is very rich.
At the end of the movie a girl whom is in love with the Euro-partying guy goes to his dorm room but there's another woman inside of the dorm room in there partying and he literally cannot remember who this girl is even though they dated or had a past of some sort.  That's about all I can remember! 
Good luck!

I think that's The Rules of Attraction, (2002).

Lauren Hynde is, technically, a virgin. She's saving herself for her
  shallow boyfriend, Victor Johnson, who's left the States to backpack
  across Europe.

I remember Victor, in Lauren's mind, being the perfect boyfriend, which is why she won't date Sean, (James Van Der Beek), but when Victor comes home he has completely forgotten her.  I also remember the montage you describe.
